# Update data in database using vb and sql

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

i want to update the data using textbox in a database but i get the error message. the error is "Incorrect syntax near '('."

below is the code for update data

hopefully u all can help me to solve the problem. Thanks :)

```
dbSource = "Data Source=LAILATUL-PC\SERVER;Initial Catalog=HotelManagementSystem;Integrated Security=True"

            con = New SqlConnection(dbSource)

            con.Open()

            Dim sqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE [Room] SET ([Room_Code], [Room_Type], [Room_No], [Room_Price], [Room_Status], [No_of_Occupancy]) VALUES (@RoomCode, @RoomType, @RoomNo, @RoomPrice, @RoomStatus, @NoOfOccupancy WHERE [Room_Code] = " & txtRoomCode.Text & " ) "

            cmd = New SqlCommand(sqlUpdate)

            cmd.Connection = con


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomCode", txtRoomCode.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomType", txtRoomType.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomNo", txtRoomNo.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomPrice", txtRoomPrice.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RoomStatus", txtRoomStatus.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NoOfOccupancy", txtNoOfOccupancy.Text)


            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()



            MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already using parameters don't forget the last one which could open your `sql` up to injection attacks.

```
Dim sqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE [Room] SET [Room_Code] = @RoomCode, 
    [Room_Type] = @RoomType, [Room_No] = @RoomNo, [Room_Price] = @RoomPrice
    [Room_Status] = @RoomStatus, [No_of_Occupancy] = @NoOfOccupancy
    WHERE [Room_Code] = @RoomCode"
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to quote the room code text in the WHERE clause

```
Dim sqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE [Room] SET ([Room_Code], [Room_Type], [Room_No], [Room_Price], [Room_Status], [No_of_Occupancy]) VALUES (@RoomCode, @RoomType, @RoomNo, @RoomPrice, @RoomStatus, @NoOfOccupancy WHERE [Room_Code] = '" & txtRoomCode.Text & "' ) "
```

**Edit**
Or better yet make that a parameter too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this statement:

```
Dim sqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE [Room] SET ([Room_Code], [Room_Type], [Room_No], [Room_Price], [Room_Status], [No_of_Occupancy]) VALUES (@RoomCode, @RoomType, @RoomNo, @RoomPrice, @RoomStatus, @NoOfOccupancy WHERE [Room_Code] = " & txtRoomCode.Text & " ) "
```

needs to be rewritten as follows:

```
Dim sqlUpdate As String = "UPDATE [Room] SET [Room_Code] = @RoomCode, [Room_Type] = @RoomType,  [Room_No] = @RoomNo, [Room_Price] = @RoomPrice, [Room_Status] = @RoomStatus, [No_of_Occupancy] = @NoOfOccupancy WHERE [Room_Code] = '" & txtRoomCode.Text & "' ) "
```

You have two problems. You didn't quote your txtRoomCode.txt value, and that's not the correct syntax for an UPDATE statement, unless I'm really confused.